# Memory - 20Gb being used by something

Tags: insufficient-memory

Apologies that this is a similar question but I have not yet found the solution here.  I have 32 Gb A6, apps consume around 10Gb and I have a ton on SD card but storage info says I only have 2Gb free on internal memory.[image: see below I hope]

Have downloaded X-plore but I am either too stupid to figure it out or it does not easily show what the issue is.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The dialog only shows your data but it does not show how much space Android itself consumes. Assuming a dual system partition about 10 GB or more can be used by the Android OS itself. Use [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) app to see the partition layout.

Comment: Thanks Robert - git this from DiskInfo.  (Cannot paste picture)

Comment: --------------------------
 Internal Storage
--------------------------
 * Data [/data] (/data) [ext4]
   Used: 21.9 GB, Free: 2.9 GB, Total space: 24.8 GB
 * Cache [/cache] (/cache) [ext4]
   Used: 5.9 MB, Free: 186 MB, Total space: 192 MB

Comment: How can I find where all that data is being used?

Comment: delete your WhatsApp folder

Comment: Thanks Alecxs - dont have WhatsApp on it

Comment: Now you know that your system already occupies 7.2GB and you can only use 24.8 of 32 GB. For more details on app and data usage use the storage overview in Android settings. Apps on unrooted devices don't have access to data of other apps, hence an app can never show you the data usage.

Comment: Thanks Robert - will just try deleting stuff and see what happens :)

Comment: Try this settings>storage>cached data click on it then click on ok, it will free much space without losing anything just give it try even i got same problem like you but for 2gb not 30gb still worth try it

Comment: 2nd option is you can connect your phone with pc or laptop with USB Cable as MTP storage aka removable device then see internal storage size and if its full open it and check property of each folder size then delete that folder or useless data.